# Get specific date range

Tags: mysql

I'm using

```
SELECT * from tbl_name WHERE DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```

to select data for specific days. The problem is that line gets data right before 3 days. 
What to do so selected data to be period three days before till now ?

Comment: Can you make an example?

Comment: I mean, can you make an example of the kind of date that this catches that you don't want to catch?

Comment: Lets say I wan't to get all data since 2011-10-10 till now 2011-10-13. With the query above I get data only for 2011-10-10 but not for 2011-10-11 etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First your field should be of type `datetime` or `date` and then you can use a `between` clause

```
your_date_field BETWEEN now() - INTERVAL 72 HOURS AND now()
```

Comment: What is wrong with that query ?

SELECT * from cars where added BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 72 HOURS AND NOW() ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0

Comment: I never used offset, I would do this with LIMIT 0,15.